# How do I publish a QT LGPL program

Tags: c++, qt4, qmake

I believe I have too dynamically link my program. How do I link my program too QT and then install it by an nsis installer, on Windows? Do I use QMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ship your program with the Qt dll's you have used - assuming you have made no changes to the Qt source.

On linux you can assume they have the correct dlls or will get them from their distribution's repository automatically with the  dependencies checker.
On windows you really need the Dlls for the same compilers so it's safer for you to include them.

If you have changed the Qt source for your own needs then you need to offer the new Qt source to any of the downloaders - otherwise just a note pointing them at qt.nokia.com would be enough.